# add a new function in if else jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery code works so that **if** it does not find a my value, it will `display: none;`. I would like to add to this, in addition to hiding, another div class was another css. how to add this to this condition?

I would like, that additionally `$(".footer").css("position", "fixed");`

```
var $rows = $('.col-md-3');

$('.form-control').keyup(function() {
    var val = '^(?=.*\\b' + $.trim($(this).val()).split(/\s+/).join('\\b)(?=.*\\b') + ').*$',
        reg = RegExp(val, 'i'),
        text;

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
        return !reg.test(text); //sprawdzamy czy wiersz pasuje doelementu szukanego, jeśli nie to chowamy ten wiersz
    }).css("display", "none");
```

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: Your question is bit confusing, what value, why condition, and on which div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning the result of the test directly, use it in an `if()` that does what you want, then returns the result.

```
$rows.show().filter(function() {
    text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    if (!reg.test(text)) {
        $otherDiv.css("color", "red");
        return true;
    }
}).hide();
```

I also recommend using `.hide()` and `.show()` rather than `.css()`.